# trouble in passing select tag values in a rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

new on rails, i am having problem in passing select_tag value(in the view file) to controller.

my view controller file is like

```
class ProjectStatusController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @projects = Project.find(:all, :select => "name")
  end

  def show
    lookup = params[:project]
    @rows = Project.find_by_lookup(lookup)
  end
end
```

and view file is like

```
<% form_tag("project_status", :controller => "ProjectStatus", :action => "show",    :method=>'get' ) do %>
<%= select_tag 'project', options_from_collection_for_select(@projects,"id", "name"),:onchange => "this.form.submit();" %>
<% end %>
<% 
if !@rows.nil? 
 @rows.each do |row|
end 
%>
<%= row[:name] %>
<% end %>
```

what i basically want to achieve is this - based on the selected value from select tag
i want to display information(on the same view page) of selected item from the database

Comment: show your routes.rb file, please

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should write `<%= form_tag` not `<% form_tag`

Than, it's strange that your extract for select field `id`(`options_from_collection_for_select(@projects,"id", "name")`)

but in method show you search record by field lookup

Comment: well regarding select tag, i am filling my select tag from other class through database. u can assume that select tag is having some values. and then i want the selected value passed onto a controller.

Comment: i am working on redmine. so the project's routes file is too large to show here.

Comment: pardon i dint get you. how can i get selected value from drop down in a lookup variable and how do i call show method from the view file. i have pasted my view and controller file in the question.

Comment: now i am getting value in url.. added id in select i.e.  :select => "name, id".. and on selecting any option it shows following error Unknown action

No action responded to 7(where 7 is selected option value).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something of this sort to get this issue fixed

```
     <%= check_box_tag "projectids[]",project.id %>
```

This would display the checkbox against each entry. And the checkbox is linked to the project object by its id. In the controller method, you will receive the project ids.

Then just directly use the submit tag to pass the parameters to the method.